# How to write javascript loop function that will take an array as a parametr?

Tags: javascript

I have array called “MyArray” and containing the values 1,2,3,4,5. Need to Write a javascript loop function that will take an array similar to the one described in the previous function as a parameter and print the value at each index of the array (ie MyArray[0], MyArray[1], etc).

Comment: Guess SO should allow account creation only after people pass certain tests.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide sample input-output data and what have you tried so far to accomplish the result.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function printMyArray(myArray) {
  myArray.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
  });
}

printMyArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function though. Try this ES6 way.

```js
const MyArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(...MyArray);
```